# Ant/Grails test-app with cobertura causes: CreateProcess error=206, The filename or extension is too long

Tags: java, grails, ant

We have an ant build that is creating our production ear. It invokes Grails scripts. We also have the code-coverage plugin added to our Grails project to do instrumentation. Everything works fine when running it using just "grails test-app", but when we invoke it through Ant, we get the following error: CreateProcess error=206, The filename or extension is too long. I've seen this error in the past, and I believe it is usually due to the classpath being too long. The server that this is running on is a 64bit Windows 2008 server.

The ant target looks like this:

```
<target name="test-cobertura"
        description="--> Run a Grails applications unit and integration tests with code coverage">
    <!-- <echo message="GRAILS_HOME ${myenv.GRAILS_HOME}"/> -->
    <exec executable="${grails}" failonerror="false" resultproperty="resultCode">
        <arg value="test-app"/>
        <arg value="-xml"/>
        <arg value="-Xms512m"/>
        <arg value="-Xmx1024m"/>
        <arg value="-coverage"/>
    </exec>
    <junitreport todir="target/test-reports/html">
      <fileset dir="target/test-reports/">
        <include name="TEST-*.xml"/>
      </fileset>
      <report format="frames" todir="target/test-reports/html"/>
    </junitreport>

    <zip basedir="target/test-reports/html" destfile="test/reports/testReport.zip"/>
    <fail status="1" message="Some tests failed">
        <condition>
            <equals arg1="${resultCode}" arg2="1"/>
        </condition>
    </fail>
    <zip basedir="target/test-reports/cobertura" destfile="test/reports/cobertura.zip"/>
</target>
```

If we turn the coverage piece off, it runs fine, so it's definitely the cobertura piece that is causing the error.

We've been playing around with it but cannot figure anything out at this point. Any help would be greatly appreciated.